# Problem encountered in react native run android

Tags: react-native

I recently installed React Native on my Windows PC and I created a project but when i try with react-native run-android for android emulator it shows me:

```
C:\ReactNative\testproj>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\ReactNative\testproj\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\ReactNative\testproj\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (C:\ReactNative\testproj\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Please help

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly, go through the setup again, everything should works...

Comment: Sir how do you mean "go through the setup again"? I browse my JAVA_HOME path in env like this C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221, is it correct?

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-java_home-in-windows-10 Maybe this will help! Check out what is missing there...

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you Sir!

Comment: Glad that helped! Do mark my answer as solution please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly, go through the setup again, everything should works... 
You can refer to [this](http://thewindowsclub.com/set-java_home-in-windows-10) and check what is missing...

Comment: For me, it worked after updating nodejs to latest version.